# How to integrate Google IDP with Azure ad b2c sign in user flow?

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api

I'm trying to integrate Google identity provider to sign in user flow in Azure Ad B2C. while logging in with google id and password its redirecting to the page which I have provided but with an error **"User does not exist. Please sign up before you can sign in."**

It's working fine with **Facebook** Idp

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `SignIn` only (and not `SignUporSignIn flow`), this behavior is expected if the user does not exist in the directory.

If you use a `SignUporSignIn flow`, user will be prompted to signup if they don't exist.